# I keep getting error when using get_string CS50

Tags: c, cs50

when i am using 'get_string' i am recieveing this error message. i have included <cs50.h> ! please could anyone helpas i cant figure out what I'm doing wrong

```
adability.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o readability
readability.c:9:19: error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant
    string text = get_string ("Text: ") ;
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/cs50.h:109:25: note: expanded from macro 'get_string'
#define get_string(...) get_string(NULL, __VA_ARGS__)
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: The initialiser is not a constant. (which means: it calls a function, which cannot  be done at compile time, Or: it happens at global scope)

Comment: @Carcigenicate It is a typedef alias for `char *`, and one that historically has done far, far more harm to people new to C than it has ever, *ever* helped. The `get_string` ideology (and many other such nuances) from that abominable header/lib is intended to "shield" students from the very thing they should be learning.

Comment: Is `string text = get_string ("Text: ") ;` outside of a function? You can't do that. Initializers of global variables (technically, for variables with static storage) must be constant.

Comment: thank you! i have managed to fix the problem :)